If $f,\ g: A \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $A$ a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $\{x\in A\ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\}$ is open
If $f,\ g: A \to \mathbb{R}$ are continuous and $A$ a open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ then $\{x\in A \ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\}$ is open.
Let $x\in A$ such that $f(x)\not=g(x)$. WLOG set $r=f(x)-g(x)>0$, then exists some $\delta>0$ such that $|x-y| < \delta \implies (|(f-g)(y)-r|<r \iff 0 < (f-g)(y) < 2r) $. Hence, if $ y \in B(x,\delta)$, then $(f-g)(y)>0$, meaning $B(x,\delta)\subset \{x\ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\}$
As u notice, i never us the fact that $A$ is open, so i missing something here. Where did i go wrong?. I intuitively understand why A must be open.

You use the fact that $A$ is open when your claim there is a neighborhood $B(x,\delta)$ that is contained in the domains of $f,g$. (which is $A$)

How high is your level in topology? If you know that the preimage of an open set  ($\mathbb{R}^*$) by a continuous function ($f-g$) is open, then it is direct. Also  you use the fact that A is open since you know that it is open in the induced topology, here it means that any open set is of the form $A \cap U$ so since A is open, your set is still open in $\mathbb{R}$ but the phrasing lacks precision here

We should interpret "${x|f(x)\ne g(x)}$" as shorthand for ${x\in A|f(x)\ne g(x)}$ since $f$ and $g$ are not defined outside of $A$.

@Mark i see where i did wrong. Thanks

You need to use that $A$ is open to guarantee that $B(x,\delta)$ is (perhaps after shrinking $\delta$) actually in the domain of $f-g$. I.e., since $A$ is open, there exists $\delta'>0$ such that $B(x,\delta')\subseteq A$. Now let $\delta''=\min\{\delta,\delta'\}$.
To see the issue, consider what happens when $A$ is not open. E.g., let $A=\{1\}$, and $f(1)=2$, $g(1)=3$.
By the way, here is an alternate approach:
Define $h\colon A\to \Bbb R$ by $h(x)=f(x)-g(x)$. Then $\{x\in A:f(x)\neq g(x)\}$ is the complement of $h^{-1}(\{0\})$ in $A$.

Correction of your proof:
Let $x\in A$ such that $f(x)\not=g(x)$. WLOG set $r=f(x)-g(x)>0$, then exists some $\delta>0$ such that $\forall y\in A,\; |x-y| < \delta \implies (|(f-g)(y)-r|<r \iff 0 < (f-g)(y) < 2r) $. Hence, if $ y \in B(x,\delta)\cap A$, then $(f-g)(y)>0$, meaning $B(x,\delta)\cap A\subset \{x\ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\}$. Since $A$ is open, $B(x,\delta)\cap A$ is an open set contained in $\{x\ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\}$ containing $x$ and one concludes.
Briefer proof:
Note that $\{x\ |\ f(x)\not=g(x)\} = \mathscr{C}(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$. Since $\{0\}$ is closed and $f-g$ is continuous, $\mathscr{C}(f-g)^{-1}(\{0\})$ is open. ($\mathscr{C}$ is the complement operator with respecto to $\mathbb{R}$).

Let $U=\{x:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$
If $U$ is empty, then we are done because the empty set is open.
Let $p\in U$
Since $f(p)\ne g(p)$, let $\epsilon=\frac{1}{2}\lvert f(p)-g(p)\rvert$. Then the two intervals $(f(p)-\epsilon, f(p)+\epsilon)$ and $(g(p)-\epsilon, g(p)+\epsilon)$ are disjoint. Moreover, since $f$ and $g$ are continuous, there exist $\delta_f, \delta_g$ such that $$\lvert x-p\rvert\lt\delta_f\implies\lvert f(x)-f(p)\rvert\lt\epsilon\implies f(x)\in (f(p)-\epsilon, f(p)+\epsilon)$$ and $$\lvert x-p\rvert\lt\delta_g\implies\lvert g(x)-g(p)\rvert\lt\epsilon\implies g(x)\in (g(p)-\epsilon, g(p)+\epsilon)$$
Let $\delta =\text{ min($\delta_f$, $\delta_g$)}$
Then, for any $x\in(p-\delta, p+\delta)$, $$f(x)\in(f(p)-\epsilon, f(p)+\epsilon)$$
and
$$g(x)\in(g(p)-\epsilon, g(p)+\epsilon)$$ and, since those sets are disjoint, $f(x)\ne g(x)$
Therefore, $(p-\delta,p+\delta)\subset U$ and, since this is true for all $p\in U$, $U$ is open.
